# How to retry image pull in a kubernetes Pods?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, coreos

I am new to kubernetes. I have an issue in the pods. When I run the command

```
 kubectl get pods
```

Result:

```
NAME                   READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-apim-db-1viwg    1/1       Running            1          20h
mysql-govdb-qioee      1/1       Running            1          20h
mysql-userdb-l8q8c     1/1       Running            0          20h
wso2am-default-813fy   0/1       ImagePullBackOff   0          20h
```

Due to an issue of "wso2am-default-813fy" node, I need to restart it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Usually in case of "ImagePullBackOff" it's retried after few seconds/minutes. In case you want to try again manually you can delete the old pod and recreate the pod. The one line command to delete and recreate the pod would be:

```
kubectl replace --force -f <yml_file_describing_pod>
```

Comment: If you have got replication set/controller managing this pod, a new pod should be automatically created after killing it.

Comment: ^^ absolutely. I'd be very worried if killing pod had it disappear for good.

Comment: I believe `kubectl replace --force -f ...` would be equivalent to delete followed by create

Comment: If your pod created via Deployment, then just delete a pod - a new one will be created automatically

Comment: Why the `--force` option is required?

Answer (score 244):

In case of not having the yaml file:

`kubectl get pod PODNAME -n NAMESPACE -o yaml | kubectl replace --force -f -`

Answer (score 19):

```
$ kubectl replace --force -f <resource-file>
```

if all goes well, you should see something like:

```
<resource-type> <resource-name> deleted
<resource-type> <resource-name> replaced
```

details of this can be found in the Kubernetes documentation, "manage-deployment" and [kubectl-cheatsheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) pages at the time of writing.

Comment: How do I know what the resource file for the pod should look like? I saw the ./pod.json file but the link doesnt mention any template or similar

Answer (score 11):

If the `Pod` is part of a `Deployment` or `Service`, deleting it will restart the `Pod` and, potentially, place it onto another node:

`$ kubectl delete po $POD_NAME`

`replace` it if it's an individual `Pod`:

`$ kubectl get po -n $namespace $POD_NAME -o yaml | kubectl replace -f -`

Answer (score 4):

Try with deleting pod it will try to pull image again.

`kubectl delete pod <pod_name> -n <namespace_name>`

Answer (score 0):

First try to see what's wrong with the pod:

```
kubectl logs -p <your_pod>
```

**In my case it was a problem with the YAML file.**

So, I needed to correct the configuration file and replace it:

```
kubectl replace --force -f <yml_file_describing_pod>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue of ImagePullBackOff is due to either the image not being present or issue with the pod YAML file.

What I will do is this

```
kubectl get pod -n $namespace $POD_NAME --export > pod.yaml | kubectl -f apply -
```

I would also see the pod.yaml to see the why the earlier pod didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is also possibility that the pull policy is not defined or kubernetes is configured to pull from the hub but fails due network issues. Try setting up a local secure registry and execute a pull . It would work.