# Using plugin in Google Composer make it crash

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I wrote a small plugin for Apache Airflow, which runs fine on my local deployment. However, when I use Google Composer, the user interface hangs and becomes unresponsive. Is there any way to restart the webserver in Google Composer

Comment: Can you describe what the plugin you created does and add the relevant code to your question?  Can you also add what you've tried / where you've searched already?  You may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide helpful for adding more detail to the question as well.  I'm looking into the restarting bit.

Comment: I added a preliminary answer below that might help.  Let me know if it does/doesn't work for you and I'm happy to edit.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston my plugin is a backport of the dataflow runner from the current master branch, as the version in 1.9.0 wasn't not working in my environment at all. I have to say, I solved a few bugs in the master branch as well, but I didn't have the chance to create ticket and push pull requests to github yet.

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: This answer is currently more suggestive than finalized.)*

As far as restarting the webserver goes...

What doesn't work:

- I reviewed [Airflow Web Interface](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-web-interface) in the docs which describes using the webserver but not accessing it from a CLI or restarting.
- While you can also [run Airflow CLI commands](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/accessing/airflow-cli) on Composer, I don't see a command for restarting the webserver in the Airflow CLI today.
- I checked the gcloud CLI in the Google Cloud SDK but didn't find a restart related command.
  Here are a few ideas that may work for restarting the Airflow webserver on Composer:

  1. In the gcloud CLI, there's an [update command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/composer/environments/update) to change environment properties.  I would assume that it restarts the scheduler and webserver (in new containers) after you change one of these to apply the new setting.  You could set an arbitrary environment variable to check, but just running the update command with no changes may work.

     gcloud beta composer environments update ...
  2. Alternatively, you can [update environment properties](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/updating#updating_environments) excluding environment variables in the GCP Console.
  3. I think re-running the import plugins command would cause a scheduler/webserver restart as well.

     gcloud beta composer environments storage plugins import ...

In a more advanced setup, Composer supports [deploying a self-managed Airflow web server](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/deploy-webserver).  Following the linked guide, you can: connect into your Composer instance's GKE cluster, create deployment and service Kubernetes configuration files for the webserver, and deploy both with `kubectl create`.  Then you could run a [`kubectl replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046340/149428) or `kubectl delete` on the pod to trigger a fresh start.

This all feels like a bit much, so hopefully documentation or a simpler way to achieve webserver restarts emerges to succeed these workarounds.

Comment: Thanks, this is a fantastic answer. I currently installed Airflow 1.9.0 into a Compute Engine instance manually, using a Cloud SQL managed mysql instance and I can run my pipelines smoothly for now.

I did try the update command, but I didn't have luck with that. Installing a self-managed airflow web server seems to be quite a big task, almost as managing  my own installation.